# The file database.yml is not been ignored on a rails app.

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am building a rails application, on my
    .gitignore
I am trying to ignore the database.yml
    /config/database.yml
but for some reason is not been ignored.

Comment: Do you have a change in database.yml .?

Comment: If yes first delete the database.yml and then push. Or push with database.yml and next time put it into .gitignore, it will work :)

Answer (score 2):

I suppose the `config/database.yml` was already committed, therefor it is present in the repo. And `.gitignore` tells to ignore further changes to the file.

Just run this command:

```
git rm --cached config/database.yml
```